# Curse on wine not working

Tags: wine, games, crash, playonlinux

I have installed minecraft a few days ago.
I want to install a modpack from curse.
I am using wine to install a non-listed program but when I click to run the Curse.exe but this is the crash report it gives me:

```
[01/20/18 14:00:12] - Running wine- --version (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
wine-1.8

PlayOnLinux logfile
-------------------
Date: 01/20/18 14:00:12

> PlayOnLinux Version
  4.2.10
> uname -a
  Linux HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-CMT-PC 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> lsb_release -a

> wine --version
  wine-1.8
> POL_WINEVERSION

> WINEPREFIX
  /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Twitch
> Distribution
  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
> glxinfo \| grep rendering
  direct rendering: Yes
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, 
    GL_NV_packed_float_linear, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
> glxinfo \| grep renderer
  OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2
> OpenGL libs (Direct rendering testing)
  check_dd_x86 missing, test skipped
  check_dd_amd64 missing, test skipped

[01/20/18 14:00:13] - This is a 32bits prefix!
[01/20/18 14:00:16] - Running wine- cmd /c echo %ProgramFiles% (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
C:\Program Files
[01/20/18 14:00:20] - Running wine- winecfg (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch)
[01/20/18 14:00:49] - Running wine- /home/mauro/Downloads/TwitchSetup.exe (Working directory : /)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
err:winediag:schan_imp_init Failed to load libgnutls, secure connections will not be available.
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"system.serviceModel" in state 2
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"bindings" in state 6
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"client" in state 6
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"dependentAssembly" in state 0
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"assemblyIdentity" in state 6
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"bindingRedirect" in state 6
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy" in state 4
The entry point method could not be loaded
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
[01/20/18 14:01:55] - Running wine- winepath -u C:\\users\\mauro\\Desktop (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c)
/home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Twitch/dosdevices/c:/users/mauro/Desktop
[01/20/18 14:02:10] - Running wine- CurseUI.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin/Electron)
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:02:52] - Running wine- winepath -u C:\\users\\mauro\\Desktop (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c)
/home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/dosdevices/c:/users/mauro/Desktop
[01/20/18 14:03:21] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:03:37] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:03:50] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:05:53] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:05:59] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:14:59] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
The entry point method could not be loaded
[01/20/18 14:15:07] - Running wine- Curse.exe (Working directory : /home/mauro/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Twitch/drive_c/users/mauro/Application Data/Twitch/Bin)
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
>The entry point method could not be loaded
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: One possibility is to skip working with `Curse.exe`, to use the Linux version of Minecraft, and to download modpacks directly from [CurseForge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft).

Answer (score -1):

It worked,
Just do what this guy says you to:
https://github.com/LunaSquee/mc_curse_modpack_downloader
1. Install Node.js
2. Add a text document to your desktop named:install_pack.js
3. Add the text down below to the document then save:
4. Run this command in the termenal:node install_pack.js https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/MODPACK_NAME_HERE

Text for in the terminal:

https://github.com/LunaSquee/mc_curse_modpack_downloader/blob/master/install_pack.js

Comment: Since bad things can happen to links, please add the basic instructions from that link here in your answer.